# node.js pause for a few seconds

Tags: node.js, wait

I want my node.js program to print `foo` every 30 seconds. So I write a code like this:

```
let count = 0

function foo () {
  console.log(`foo`)
  count += 1
  // do other things that takes about 20 seconds.
}

while (count < 10) {
  console.log(`inside while loop`)  // my screen keep printing `inside while loop` until "JavaScript heap out of memory" error
  setTimeout(foo, 30000)  // It looks like that `foo` is scheduled to be triggered after 30 seconds. Before it gets triggered, node.js program keeps doing other things.
}
```

This code doesn't do what I expected.

It looks like that `foo` is scheduled to be triggered after 30 seconds. 
 Before it gets triggered, node.js program keeps doing other things.

How can I pause the program during the 30 seconds?

The program runs a few seconds, then it crashed due to `JavaScript heap out of memory` error.

The [sleep module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sleep) doesn't work. Because as it sleeps, `foo` stops doing things I need.

Comment: foo is asynchronous, so the while loop is iterating faster than those timeouts, causing heap out of memory error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is because of asynchronous nature of JavaScript

While loop makes a lot of iterations and register `setTimeout` callback.
It's better to register `setTimeout` callback after each callback execution.

```
let counter = 0;
function foo() {
  console.log(`foo ${counter}`);
  counter ++;
  if (counter < 3) {
    setTimeout(foo, 1000);
  }
}
foo();
```

another option is to use setInterval and check, if you need to cancel next execution of callback.

Comment: the above code is not working .can u share the entire code or put in online compiler

Comment: I forgot add call of `foo` function in my example. Just call it. https://repl.it/N869/1